# Function using reduce not working; returning false when should be true

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```
var atLeast = function (tab,n,k){
    var frequencyK = tab.reduce(function (acc, val, array){
        if (val == k){
            return acc+1;
        }
    });
    return frequencyK >= n;
};
console.log(atLeast([1,2,3,2,2,4,2,2],4,2));
```

This function is meant to return true if the argument *k* is repeated in the array *tab* at least *n* times. To do this I used reduce, and incremented the accumulator by 1 each time that the current value was equal to *k*. I then I compared the frequency of *k* calculated with the reduce function with *n*.

The problem is that frequencyK ends up being NaN. I can't figure out why that is.

Comment: because you do not have a return in the reduce for the else clause

Comment: What if `val != k`? What does the callback return then? What will `acc` be then?

Answer (score 3):

Reduce takes two arguments, the reduction function and the initial value, you dropped the initial value, and thus it starts with the first element, which is the wrong number.

Additionally, when you return nothing, the next `acc` gets a value of `undefined`, which won't do at all in a math operation (this gets you the NaN).

To correct this, add `0` as an initial value to `.reduce()`, and return in all cases, like so:

```
var atLeast = function (tab,n,k){
    var frequencyK = tab.reduce(function (acc, val, array){
        if (val == k){
            return acc+1;
        }
        return acc;
    }, 0);
    return frequencyK >= n;
};
console.log(atLeast([1,2,3,2,2,4,2,2],4,2));
```

However, I think the following is a simpler way:

```
const atLeast = (tab, n, k) => tab.filter(item => item === k).length >= n;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return for all cases in the reduce function.

```js
var atLeast = function (tab,n,k){
    var frequencyK = tab.reduce(function (acc, val, array){
        return val == k ? acc+1 : acc;  //return the val for both cases
    }, 0);  //<-- set zero here
    return frequencyK >= n;
};
console.log(atLeast([1,2,3,2,2,4,2,2],4,2));
```