# ES6 reduce not workd as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of called `orders`,

```
const orders = [
  {
    name: 'iPhone 7',
    price: 7199,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'iPad 2',
    price: 3399,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Macbook Pro',
    price: 19888,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Kindle Osis',
    price: 2399,
    count: 2
  }
];
```

and I want to calculate the total price by summing each item's `price` times `count` up like this:

```
orders.reduce((e1, e2) => e1.price * e1.count + e2.price * e2.count);
```

but I got **NaN** instead of the total price, anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: pass 0 as second argument

Comment: In the second iteration, `e1` will be the result of the first iteration, e.g. `25` and that has neither a price nor a count

Comment: Refer to js doc at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Certain duplicate of [Function using reduce not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230992/function-using-reduce-not-working-returning-false-when-should-be-true)

Comment: thank you guys, I mistakenly used `reduce`, and now I fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

You

- forgot to pass `0` as the initial value of a sum
- did not consider that the first argument of the callback is the *numeric* result from the previous call, not an array element with properties.

So use

```
orders.reduce((sum, el) => sum + el.price * el.count, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) a start value for the sum and multiply only the actual values.

For the values, you could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), because you need only the two propeties `price` and `count`.

```js
const orders = [{name: 'iPhone 7', price: 7199, count: 2}, {name: 'iPad 2', price: 3399, count: 1}, {name: 'Macbook Pro', price: 19888, count: 1}, {name: 'Kindle Osis', price: 2399, count: 2}],
    total = orders.reduce((sum, { price, count }) => sum + price * count, 0);
    //                                                                    ^

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
orders.reduce((accumulator, order) => accumulator + order.price * order.count, 0);
```

I think that you get the idea of reduce wrong. The first argument is an accumulator (the result of all previous of reduce's iterations) so there is no need to multiply it by anything in your case. You just calculate the price of the current order and add it to the accumulator.

The `0` is an initial value for the accumulator to use during first iteration.